# Mongodb aggregation pass argument to element size of $sample

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Hello every body here any one can help me with query below

- I want to get quiz list with random amount
- the amount of rendom will
  base on each lesson

The problem is

- mongodb not allow to pass argument to element size of $sample

Any one can give me the solution

```
lessonModel.aggregate([
        { $match : {'quiz.status':1 } },
        {
            $lookup : {
                from : 'quiz',
                let : { 'lesson_id' : '$_id','limit' : '$quiz.amount' },
                pipeline : [
                    { 
                        $match: { 
                            $expr: { 
                                $eq: [ "$lesson_id", "$$lesson_id" ]
                            } 
                        } 
                    },
                    { 
                        $project: {
                            title:1,
                            check_list:1,
                            duration:1
                        }               
                    },
                    { $sample: { size: '$$limit' } }
                ],
                as: 'quiz'
            }
        }, 
        {$unwind: '$quiz'},
        { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$quiz" } }
    ]).exec();
```

The error said size argument to $sample must be a number

Here is my sample data
[image: Sample data]

Comment: Post some data from your `lessons` collection or `lessonModel`

Comment: Please share your sample data and query using [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) :)

Comment: @DheemanthBhat I have add sample data in my post

Comment: @ray I have updated in my post please check

Comment: @DaraVichit check the updated answer if it helps your actual problem of randomly picking `amount` number of `quiz`.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I think your main problem is to randomly pick `amount` number of `quiz`s under each lesson. Since `$sample` is not helpful use [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) (New in version MongoDB 4.4).

**Solution**

Inside `$function` operator write some logic to

1. [Shuffle the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array/6274381#6274381) (You can change it to your requirement).
2. Slice it to return the number(`amount`) of questions required.

```js
db.lessons.aggregate([
    { $match: { "quiz.status": 1 } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "quiz",
            let: { "lesson_id": "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$lesson_id", "$$lesson_id"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        title: 1,
                        check_list: 1,
                        duration: 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "questions"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            quiz: {
                $function: {
                    body: function(questions, amount) {
                        if (amount == 0) return [];

                        for (let i = questions.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                            [questions[i], questions[j]] = [questions[j], questions[i]];
                        }

                        return questions.slice(0, amount);
                    },
                    args: ["$questions", { $ifNull: ["$quiz.amount", 0] }],
                    lang: "js"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$quiz" },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$quiz" } }
]);
```

`$sample` does not support variables. A number must be specified explicitly like:

```js
{ 
    $sample: { size: 1 }
}
```

Also replace your `let` as shown below because last `lesson` document has no `amount` filed in the `quiz` object

```js
let: {
    'lesson_id': '$_id',
    'limit': { $ifNull: ['$quiz.amount', 0] } // or any other number.
},
```

Wrong:

```js
{ 
    $sample: { size: "$$limit" } // Wont work!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB v5.0+, you can use assign random `$rand` to each matched documents and use `$setWindowFields` to compute `$rank` on each document. For picking `$sample` of n, just match with rank <= n.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "quiz.status": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "rand": {
        "$rand": {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "sortBy": {
        "rand": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      rank: {
        $lte: 2
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "rank",
      "rand"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r44Y3Lv-WB_)