# Fetching Random MongoDB Documents Equally Across Multiple Chapters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, random-data

I have a MongoDB collection with documents structured like this:

```
{
    "index": 23,
    "chapter": "b11"
},
{
    "index": 25,
    "chapter": "b11"
},
{
    "index": 26,
    "chapter": "b14"
},
{
    "index": 27,
    "chapter": "b14"
},
{
    "index": 28,
    "chapter": "b16"
}
```

In my collection, I have documents with an "index" field and a "chapter" field representing different chapter names.

I need to fetch a random set of documents (e.g., 20 random documents) based on specific chapter names like "b11" and "b16." The number of chapters I query may vary (e.g., I might need to fetch for three chapters like "b11," "b12," "m14"). What's crucial is that I need an equal number of random documents for each of the specified chapter names.

I understand that the total number of documents I need to retrieve should be divisible by the number of chapters I'm querying.

What's the most efficient way to achieve this using MongoDB and Node.js as my backend? Any code examples or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have attempted to fetch random documents from the MongoDB collection using a basic query, but this doesn't guarantee an equal distribution of documents across the specified chapter names. I was expecting to retrieve a balanced number of documents for each chapter name, but the results were uneven. I'm now looking for guidance on how to implement a solution that ensures an equal distribution of random documents for the provided chapter names.

Comment: Do you know the `$sample` operator, might help you !
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking to use `$sample` since @Fourchette's comment made sense to me. However, I found out that `$sample` cannot take in a variable as argurment. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384166/mongodb-aggregation-pass-argument-to-element-size-of-sample))

So I have to do followings in aggregation pipeline:

1. `$match` only the chapters you want
2. get distinct set and count for matched chapters
3. `$divide` your target number of chapter evenly across the fetched chapters
4. perform self `$lookup`. Use `$setWindowFields` to compute `$rank` within a chapter and use `$rand` as a tiebreaker
5. pick only those with rank <= num per group. e.g. if you want 10 documents in total and there are 2 matched chapters, pick those with rank <= 10 / 2 = 5

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      chapter: {
        $in: [
          "b11",
          "b14"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      chapter: {
        $addToSet: "$chapter"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      numPerChapter: {
        "$divide": [
          10,
          {
            $size: "$chapter"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$chapter"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "let": {
        numPerChapter: "$numPerChapter"
      },
      "localField": "chapter",
      "foreignField": "chapter",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $set: {
            randKey: {
              "$rand": {}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$setWindowFields": {
            "sortBy": {
              "randKey": 1
            },
            "output": {
              "rank": {
                $rank: {}
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $lte: [
                "$rank",
                "$$numPerChapter"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$unset": [
            "randKey",
            "rank"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "as": "picked"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$picked"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$picked"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hwfzhlE4E_2)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. However, the query you provided retrieves all the documents that contain the chapter name provided in $match. I tried increasing the number of documents for both b11 and b14 here:  mongoplayground.net/p/iNXJpkLsado

Comment: @Ashraf sorry. It was a typo in the nested `$match` clause. Updated the answer. Please check the updated link

Comment: Now it's working exactly as I desired. Thank you!